# Efficient way to read key=value pair from a bash file for each line to process it

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I need suggestion for a better programming in bash for processing file ( specially the key value pairs in a line)

I was trying to process a task for log lines :

1. if the word "critical/warning" appears, I should print the value of `request_id` in a new line
2. if the key `IPA` has value "MASKED" then append " MASK" with the `request_id` in output

I wrote below code to process it

```
while read line
do
  if [ $( echo "$line" | grep "critical/warning" | grep -c "request_id=") -gt 0 ]
  then
    request_id=$( echo "$line"| awk -F"request_id=" '{print $2}'| awk '{print $1}')
    if [ $(echo "$line" | grep -c "IPA=") -gt 0  ]
    then
      IPA=$(echo "$line"| awk -F"IPA=" '{print $2}'| awk '{print $1}');
      [[ "M$IPA" == "M\"MASKED\"" ]] && request_id="$request_id MASK"
    fi
    echo $request_id; 
  fi
done < test.txt
```

Below is the sample log file

```
Apr 10 11:17:35 jalaltu app/web.3: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET /backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=69dff0hba0nv HTTP/1.1" 200 148 "https://jalaltu.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Apr 10 11:17:35 critical/warning: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?key=s2fwad2Es2" host=jalaltu.com request_id=b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa IPA="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.3 connect=0ms service=92ms status=200 bytes=3194 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 critical/warning: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=jalaltu.com request_id=910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65 IPA="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=17ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 critical/warning: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=jalaltu.com request_id=097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2 IPA="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.3 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 jalaltu app/web.2: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET /backend/requests/editor/placeholder?key=s2fwad2Es2 HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "https://jalaltu.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36

Apr 10 11:17:35 critical/warning: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=4eiramcmayu0" host=jalaltu.com request_id=d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8 IPA="108.31.000.000" dyno=web.4 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=3194 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:35 jalaltu app/web.3: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET /backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "https://jalaltu.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36

Apr 10 11:17:35 jalaltu app/web.3: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET /backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "https://jalaltu.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36

Apr 10 11:17:36 jalaltu app/web.4: IP_MASKED - - [10/Apr/2020:18:17:35 +0000] "GET /backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=4eiramcmayu0 HTTP/1.1" 200 3023 "https://jalaltu.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36

Apr 10 11:17:36 critical/warning: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=jalaltu.com request_id=8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca IPA="MASKED" dyno=web.3 connect=1ms service=32ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https

Apr 10 11:17:36 critical/warning: at=info method=GET path="/backend/requests/editor/placeholder?shareLinkId=tosrve4v8q8q" host=jalaltu.com request_id=10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a IPA="MASKED" dyno=web.3 connect=1ms service=37ms status=200 bytes=4435 protocol=https
```

Below is the output from sample log file

```
b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca MASK
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a MASK
```

Comment: I wouldn't write this in `bash` at all. Other languages can read a file line-by-line much more quickly.

Comment: @chepner, thanks for the good suggestion but the requirement is to write in bash so I have to

Comment: You're already not writing this in (just) `bash`; `grep` and `awk` are separate programs; you might as well write a single `awk` (or `python`, or `perl`, or `ruby`, or ...) script.

Comment: To be clear, you can replace all of the `awk` and `grep` calls with `bash`'s own regular-expression matching, but you asked for an *efficient* way to do this, and that's not `bash`.

Comment: @markp-fuso, its is required .. I just missed it to paste the whole code here 
Updating the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- while the sample data shows `request_id` always coming before `IPA`, I'm going to assume this may not always be the case

One idea using a single `awk` invocation (which should be a bit faster than the current `bash` looping construct with several sub-process calls to `echo/grep/awk`):

```
awk '
/critical[/]warning/ &&                                           # if line contains "critical/warning" and ...
/request_id/ { mask=""                                            # line contains "request_id", clear the "mask" variable
               for (i=1 ; i<=NF; i++)                             # loop through our input fields 
                   { split($(i),arr,"=")                          # split current field on "=", store results in array "arr[]"
                     if ( arr[1] == "request_id" )                # if field is "request_id" ...
                        { reqid = arr[2] }                        # save the associated id
                     if ( arr[1] == "IPA" && arr[2] ~ "MASKED" )  # if field is "IPA" and value matches "MASKED" ...
                        { mask = " MASK"  }                       # set our "mask" variable
                   }
                print reqid mask                                  # print our variables
             }
' log.dat
```

**NOTE**: Remove comments to declutter code

The above generates:

```
b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca MASK
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a MASK
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach with with GNU `awk`:

```
awk '/critical\/warning/{
       id=gensub(/.*=/,"","g",$1)   # remove "request_id=" from $1
       if(/IPA="MASKED"/){
         print id,"MASK"
       }
       else{
         print id
       }
     }' FPAT='request_id=[a-z0-9-]{36}' file
```

Output:

```
b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca MASK
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a MASK
```

From `man awk`:

`FPAT`:        A  regular  expression describing the contents of the fields in a record

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus for adding a different solution, a good point for me to learn .. I did not know about FPAT

Answer (score 0):

One `bash` solution (sans `awk/grep/echo`) using some pattern matching and parameter expansion ... though for large files this won't be as fast as a solution with a single `awk` invocation ...

```
while read -r line
do
    [[ ! "${line}" =~ "critical/warning" ]] && continue     # if line does not contain "critical/warning" then skip to next line

    if [[ "${line}" =~ "request_id=" ]]                     # if line includes string "request_id=" ...
    then
        reqid="${line#*request_id=}"                        # strip off everything up to and including "request_id="
        reqid="${reqid%% *}"                                # then strip off everything from the first space to the end of the variable
    fi

    mask=""                                                 # clear our mask string
    [[ "${line}" =~ 'IPA="MASKED"' ]] && mask=" MASK"       # if line includes string 'IPA="MASKED"' then set our "mask" variable

    printf "%s%s\n" "${reqid}" "${mask}"                    # print our variables

done < log.dat
```

This generates:

```
b19a87a1-1bbb-4e67-b207-bd9f23d46afa
910b07d1-3f71-4347-a1a7-bfa20384ef65
097bf65e-e189-4f9f-9dfb-4758cff411b2
d48278c2-5731-464e-be38-ab9ad84ac4a8
8bb2413c-3c67-4180-8091-000313b8d9ca MASK
10f93da3-2753-48a3-9485-857a93d8a88a MASK
```

Comment: I tried on  a sample string but this operation does not strip off "line#*request_id="

Comment: which line from the sample data (in the question) is not being parsed properly by this code?  if you're testing data that's not in the question, please update the question with the additional test data